# Why does ExpressionContext.expression() return a list instead of a single ExpressionContext in java-ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr4

I a Java.g4 grammar. The expression parsing rule looks like this:

```
expression
    :   primary
    |   expression '.' Identifier
    |   expression '.' 'this'
    |   expression '.' 'new' nonWildcardTypeArguments? innerCreator
    |   expression '.' 'super' superSuffix
    |   expression '.' explicitGenericInvocation
    |   expression '[' expression ']'
    |   expression '(' expressionList? ')'
    |   'new' creator
    |   '(' type ')' expression
    |   expression ('++' | '--')
    |   ('+'|'-'|'++'|'--') expression
    |   ('~'|'!') expression
    |   expression ('*'|'/'|'%') expression
    |   expression ('+'|'-') expression
    |   expression ('<' '<' | '>' '>' '>' | '>' '>') expression
    |   expression ('<=' | '>=' | '>' | '<') expression
    |   expression 'instanceof' type
    |   expression ('==' | '!=') expression
    |   expression '&' expression
    |   expression '^' expression
    |   expression '|' expression
    |   expression '&&' expression
    |   expression '||' expression
    |   expression '?' expression ':' expression
    |   <assoc=right> expression
        (   '='
        |   '+='
        |   '-='
        |   '*='
        |   '/='
        |   '&='
        |   '|='
        |   '^='
        |   '>>='
        |   '>>>='
        |   '<<='
        |   '%='
        )
        expression
    ;
```

But when I look at a generated `ExpressionContext` type, Is see that calling `expression()` will return a `List<JavaParser.ExpressionContext>` instead of a single `ExpressionContext`. It does not make sense according to the grammar above.

For this code to be generated I would expect there to be a rule saying `expression : expressionList`, but clearly there is none such rule. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: because there may be zero to two expressions involved in the concrete case.

- If it is a `primary`, `ExpressionContext.expression()` will return an empty list since there is no expression matched.
- If it's an `expression '&' expression`, it will return the two `expression`s.
- If it's an `expression '.' Identifier`, it will return the single `expression`.

What you can do is something like this:

```
expression
   :   primary
   |   idExpr = expression '.' Identifier
   |   thisExpr = expression '.' 'this'
   //..
   |   leftAndExpression = expression '&&' rightAndExpression = expression
```

Then you can access them by name like `ExpressionContext.leftAndExpression` (if this option really matches).

Comment: Yes, I see that now. It seems to me that it holds for any N-Ary operation.

Comment: It holds for any sub-rule referenced in a rule. If you want a field (like `.leftAndExpression` instead of a method like `.expression()` you have to used names sub-rules (the `<name> =` part in front of a subrule).

Comment: In the case of certain syntax errors, grammar labels can fail to be assigned even though a node for that element does exist in the parse tree. For this reason, and also for memory efficiency, I recommend avoiding the use of labeled grammar elements whenever possible.

Comment: @280Z28 I prefer them for clarity reasons, but didn't know that may be not assigned in all cases. Can you provide a link that describes the circumstances under which they may not be valid? I assume that at least if the parsing is without errors, they are always valid?